# ReactiveX and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, reactivex, rxdart

I have a class `Too`

```
class Too{
 bool isLogged = false;
 BehaviorSubject suject = BehaviorSubject<bool>();

 Too({required this.isLogged}){
   suject = new BehaviorSubject<bool>.seeded(isLogged);
 }

void login(){
  isLogged = true;
  suject.sink.add(isLogged);
}

void logOut(){
  isLogged = false;
  suject.sink.add(isLogged);
}
void dispose(){
  suject.close();
}
```

and I also have the `Foo` class:

```
class Foo{
  Too _too = new Too(isLogged: false);
  
 _too.stream.listen((event) { print('${event}');});
}
```

My issue is When the user is calling the `login()` method of the `Too` class nothing happens at the level of the Foo class.

What I want to do is that if the user calls the `login()` method of the Too class and his `isLogged` attribute is set to true, then this change is done at the level of all the classes that have an attribute of the `Too` type.

Note: It's much easier to do it with Angular or Ionic using RxJS, but with dart, I don't know how to implement this mechanism.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Foo` is not reacting because its listening to a different instance of `Too`.

The way you have it is that each new instance of `Foo` creates a new `instance` of `Too`. If I understand you correctly, you want all instances of `Foo` to react to any change to a single instance of `Too`.

You can use a singleton for this.

```
class Too {
  // one of a few ways to make a singleton in Dart
  Too._();
  static final _instance = Too._();
  factory Too() {
    return _instance;
  }

  final subject = BehaviorSubject<bool>.seeded(isLogged);

  static bool isLogged = false;

  void login() {
    isLogged = true;
    subject.sink.add(isLogged);
  }

  void logOut() {
    isLogged = false;
    subject.sink.add(isLogged);
  }

  void dispose() {
    subject.close();
  }
}
```

Now you can have any `Foo` object listen to the same `Too` instance.

```
class Foo {
  Foo() {
    Too().subject.stream.listen((event) {
      print('foo $event'); // this will now print whenever a subject from your Too class is updated. 
    });
  }
}
```

Now for example you could test this by creating a button with this as the onPressed.

```
onPressed: () {
 final foo = Foo(); // just created an example of a Foo object that will 
 // print the updated value of the Too singleton
 Too().login();
},
```

RxDart is great. However when it comes to reactive programming in Flutter, I suggest checking out [Get X](https://pub.dev/packages/get) as it simplifies a lot of stream based stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just adapted your code to mine and everything works as expected

So if I understand correctly, before I didn't have the result I wanted because I was creating each time a new Too instance in Foo

Comment: No problem, and yes you understand correctly.